# PrimeNg autocomplete suggestions list show empty strings when typing slow

Tags: angular, autocomplete, primeng

When typing in some characters inside my autocomplete field I typically get a list of results from my backend as suggestions.

Now when I type 'slow' (+- 0.5 seconds per character or slower) I still get a (correct amount) list of suggestions but they all show as blank. 
When I click a blank suggestion I do get the right information shown inside the field.

```
filteredCareProviderListDetail: string [];



ngOnInit() {
this.filteredCareProviderListDetail = [];
}

 getFilteredCareProviderList(event) {
const query = event.query;
if (query !== undefined && query !== null) {
  this.careProviderRequestService.getCareProvidersStartingWith(query)

    .subscribe(
      (response) => {
        if (response !== null) {
          this.filteredCareProviderList = response.map(cp => cp.id);
          this.filteredCareProviderListDetail = response.map(cp => cp.id + ' ' + cp.firstName + ' ' + cp.lastName);
        }
      });

}
```

}

and then the html

```
<p-autoComplete id="band" formControlName="nihdi"
                        [suggestions]="filteredCareProviderList"
                        (completeMethod)="getFilteredCareProviderList($event)"
                        [maxlength]="11"
                        [minLength]="2"
                        [forceSelection]="true"
                        (onSelect)="submitBandForm()"
                        [size]="18"
                        [immutable]="false">

          <ng-template let-carePorvider pTemplate="item" let-i="index"
                       *ngIf="filteredCareProviderListDetail != null && filteredCareProviderList != null">
            <div class="ui-helper-clearfix" style="border-bottom:1px solid #D5D5D5">
              <div style="font-size:12px;float:left;margin:5px 5px 0 0">{{filteredCareProviderListDetail[i]}}</div>
            </div>
          </ng-template>

        </p-autoComplete>
```

the [immutable]= false I've added because I came across it somewhere while googling this issue where they seemed to say that it should help but it doesn't. I might've misunderstood the answer though.

Currently working on angular 4.4 and primeng 4.2

Edit:
I've also noticed now that it doesn't happen with every suggestion, e.g. if I start with 64 I will get 2 suggestions: FIRST one will be 64123 and the SECOND one might be 64999.
Now if I type one more to specify that I want the 64999 it will show a blank result; however if I type 641 it will show me 64123 correctly.

To go even further on that , if I type 649, I get a blank suggestion as I've said, but if I start typing 64911 (so an incorrect one, it should not show me suggestions) it still shows me 1 blank suggestion and if I click it I will get the 64999.

This problem does not occur if I would type 6499 (or more characters) very quickly.

Comment: Your problem is most likely because of the Observable.

Comment: @CornelC I've just logged the 2 arrays in my observable and they do seem correct though.

Comment: I'm not saying that it's not correct, I'm saying that complete method is asynchronous and the response will arrive after a while. This may lead to unexpected behavior like the one you are having

Comment: And I also don't have a good answer since I know primeNg autocomplete had some problems with async methods. I suggest using something else like [ng-bootstrap typeahead](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples) or material angular

Comment: @CornelC Ow okay thanks for the information. :) That will probably explain the problem but I'm afraid I'll have to find a workaround because the applications has to be pure primeNG I'm afraid. :)